# Scala: given a class, distill a list of fields of class from a list of instances of that class

Tags: scala, collections, extract

assume in Scala I have something like:

```
class NSV(val name:String,val value:String) {
}
```

and a List of NSV. There is a one-shot way to extract all the "name" properties from the instances contained into the List and store them in a new List?
Something like:

```
val names:List[String] = ... ?
```

Comment: `nsvList.map(_.name)` doesn't work for you ?

Comment: @Jamil - Maybe you should make that an answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
val names = nsvList.map(_.name)
```